# Read Excel sectioned data, transform, then output to raw format for database

Tags: python, excel, database, pandas, xlrd

I don't know if this is possible.. haven't come across this on the webs. In excel I have formatted crosstab data sectioned by location/city all in the same spread sheet for thousands of rows. Simple example below.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTHHK.png)

I want to run a python excel parser that takes this formatted data and un-formats it in a raw data format so that I can load it in a database table. Is this possible? Desired result would look something like this.

[Target output Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGW32.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please show what code yo're using so far ans where you're having the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has a method to read Excel files, which is rather neat, as you get a dataframe out of it and that probably makes it easier for scanning and customized parsing.

```
import pandas as pd

# Reads the excel file
xl = pd.ExcelFile(file_path)
# Parses the desired sheet
df = xl.parse(sheet_name)

# To host all your table title indices
tbl_title = []

# To locate the title of your tables, I think you can do a sampling of that column to ascertain all the row numbers that contain the table titles
for i, n in enumerate(df.loc[:, column_name]):
    if n == 'P': # The first column in your table header as the cue
        tbl_title.append(i - 1) # This would be the row index for Frisco, Dallas etc.
```

Once you have the indices of all your table titles, you can just create another table reader function to iterate over the dataframe at the specific rows.